# Angular2 Material md-select not inline with md-input

Tags: css, angular, material-design, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm trying to create a form with [Angular2 Material](https://material.angular.io/) and bootstrap grid,
my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 marign-top-10 margin-bottom-10">
        <md-input-container class="full-width">
            <input
                mdInput
                type="text"
                formControlName="postal"
                placeholder="Postal">
        </md-input-container>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 marign-top-10 margin-bottom-10">
        <div class="full-width">
            <md-select class="full-width" placeholder="Country" formControlName="country_id">
                <md-option *ngFor="let country of countries" value="{{country.id}}">{{ country.name }}</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my full-width css class just set width:100%.

the problem is that the inputs are not in the same line as it should be
here is a few screenshots:(my application is right to left language so ignore the text direction )

[image: input and select not in the same line]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it is a css problem you can add this to your component stylesheet:

```
.mat-select{
      margin-top:10px;
 }
```

Play with the value maybe is greater than 10 or lower

Answer (score 0):

It a problem with md-select styles, I had trouble in project too, so my solution is:

CSS

```
md-select {
    min-height: 30px; // or any value that equal md-input-container>input height
}
```

JSFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/b7swupsq/)

Comment: i copied your JSFiddle example and I'm getting this error now: "Error: md-input-container must contain an mdInput directive. Did you forget to add mdInput to the native input or textarea element"

Comment: Because my example is angular1, so you should keep using angular2-material construction  `<input mdInput placeholder="Postal" formControlName="postal">`